# Negative Lookahead over multiple lines

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I wanted to replace "keepalive" with "keepalive 10 60", if not valid configured or insert "keepalive 10 60" if "keepalive" is not found.

So far I've come up with this, but it still inserts at every blank line while "keepalive" is beíng found and replaced:

```
^keepalive(?!(\s[[:digit:]]{1,3}){2}).*\n|((?<!keepalive)^$(?!keepalive))
```

**Scenario 1:**

```
keepalive 60

resolv-retry infinite
```

Expected:

```
keepalive 60 90

resolv-retry infinite
```

Outcome:

```
keepalive 60 90
keepalive 60 90

resolv-retry infinite
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
resolv-retry infinite
```

Expected:

```
keepalive 60 90

resolv-retry infinite
```

Outcome:

```
keepalive 60 90

keepalive 60 90

resolv-retry infinite
```

I'm very inexperienced with regex and would really appreciate any guidance and tips!

Comment: For the given scenarios: https://regex101.com/r/0fgOWA/9

Comment: Thanks, but I also wanted to do the same thing with "resolv-retry infinite", so it doesn't fit my use case. The problem seems to be that (negative) Lookahead/Lookbehind doesn't scan the whole file.

Comment: Perhaps like this https://regex101.com/r/7JcLGx/1

Comment: The same problem as before, but thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps:

step 1: Normalize the text by removing "keepalive 60"

```
      re.sub(r"keepalive +\d{2}","", your_str)
      #Adjust for "\n" as necessary
```

step 2: Replace "resolv-retry infinite" with whatever you want.

```
       re.sub(r"resolv-retry infinite","whatever your want", your_str)
       #adjust for "\n" as necessary
```

Comment: I wanted to add "resolv-retry infinite" if not in the string or, for example replace "resolv-retry 5" and the same with "keepalive 60". Anyway, because I needed this for a bash script I ended up just using "sed -i -E 's/^.*keepalive.*$//gm;t;d' $config_file" and
"printf "\nkeepalive 10 60" >> $config_file" although it would have been nice to use one regex (command?).